# GA API Filter Failure: Invalid value 'ga:userGender == female' for filters parameter."

Tags: filter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I tried to add a filter to extract data only from female users, but encounter the following error:

> Invalid value 'ga:userGender == female' for filters parameter.

This is my code:

```
query.list <- Init(start.date = "2015-10-09", end.date = "2016-10-09", dimensions = "ga:userAgeBracket", metrics = "ga:users,ga:pageviews,ga:sessions", filter = "ga:userGender == female", max.results = 10000, table.id = "ga:xxxxxxxx")
ga.query <- QueryBuilder(query.list) cga.data <- GetReportData(ga.query, oauth_token)
```

I do not understand what I did wrong -- I thought my code was correct.

Comment: **white spaces**. change `ga:userGender == female` to `ga:userGender==female`. Remove the white spaces around the ` == `.

Comment: It works! Thank you Matt